# Multiple Lathliss, Dragon Queen - multiple Dragon tokens?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I have 2 of the same creature in play and I activate the ability by playing another card, does it trigger twice since I have 2 of them or does it only activate once?

Example:
I have 2 [Lathliss, Dragon Queen](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLathliss%2c%20Dragon%20Queen%5d) and 1 [Mirror Gallery](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMirror%20Gallery%5d) (so I can have both out) in play.
I play Archwing Dragon triggering the ability to create a 5/5 Dragon with Flying.

Would this create two 5/5 Dragons with Flying or just one?

Comment: Cards in MTG are usually quite precise in their language, and mean exactly what they say. Specifically, if two events (the triggers of the two Lathlisses) don't refer explicitly to one another, then they are entirely as independent as the rules allow them to be (one will happen before the other because the game only permits one resolution at a time, but that's it).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll get two Dragon tokens.

Lathliss, Dragon Queen's ability is a triggered ability; each card's ability goes on the stack separately and will resolve separately. It doesn't really matter that they're identical *cards*; they're different *permanents*.